# PushNotification VolleyError at first time and 2nd time its working

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I call the **PrepareNotificationToAdmin** function first time **onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)** is coming. When again I call this function then only it's getting success. It means 2nd time its working.

Can anyone find out the error.

```
private void PrepareNotificationToAdmin() {

        database.collection("xxxx").document("xxxx").get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        AdminDeviceToken = documentSnapshot.getString("deviceToken");
                    }
                });

        NOTIFICATION_TITLE = "New Kiranam Registration";
        NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE =  loggedUserId + " - Has registered new kiranam as " + KiranamName;

        JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject notifcationBody = new JSONObject();
        try {
            notifcationBody.put("title", NOTIFICATION_TITLE);
            notifcationBody.put("message", NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);

            notification.put("to", AdminDeviceToken);
            notification.put("data", notifcationBody);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        sendNotification(notification);
    }

    private void sendNotification(JSONObject notification) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(FCM_API, notification,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        new OneToast(Register.this, "Request error");
                        //Todo: request error on first time only//
                        Log.i(TAG, "onErrorResponse: Didn't work");
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Authorization", serverKey);
                params.put("Content-Type", contentType);
                return params;
            }
        };
        MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

Comment: @david-wasser, kindly suggest me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got a solution for this. The main problem is due to the delay in getting device token from server of Admin. Before this, Notification function is getting processed and result is fail.

Now this issue is resolved.